# Can NGINX work as Webserver and Proxy Server At Same Time?

Tags: nginx, web, reverse-proxy

We have a situation where we need to serve the login page from server_A (NGINX), get the user authenticated from here and once authenticated route the request ta a page which resides in a different server i.e. Server_B. All subsequent requests will come to Server_A and it will first check the user and session validity and then route to Server_B. This way the session and security is maintained by server A and rest of the work is done by server B.

My question here is that can we acheive this from NGINX server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question here is that can we acheive this from NGINX server ?

Yes, certainly.

How do you do that?

Taking for an example a modified  Tomcat behind NGINX application config I have handy:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    location /{
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
        proxy_pass http://servera.example.com:8080/app;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
    }
    location /login{
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
        proxy_pass http://serverb.example.com:8080/login;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
    }
}
```

This will both proxy requests to the TomCat server, and serve them like any HTTP server.

Same can be said for any application you may want to proxy to, just modify the `proxy_pass` line of the above config accordingly!